# Please help me to install snippy.sh

Tags: command-line, software-installation, scripts

I use phraseexpress on my desktop pc and I find it saves me lots of typing.

Snippy seems to be an alternative for Ubuntu, I found details about it at https://tuxdiary.com/2015/03/07/snippy/ but the instructions are a bit terse for me.

I ran the terminal commands listed in the section "Installation", but then I stalled when I hit "Usage". I don't know

1. how to create a keyboard shortcut to run Snippy
2. how to create the ~/.snippy directory, I don't understand what path the "~" means

I would be very grateful if someone would help me with these two points.

Comment: `~` is your personal folder

Answer (score 2):

I will start with the `~/.snippy` creation first:

1. In Linux and in Ubuntu `~` means `/home/your_username` so `~/` simply means `/home/your_username/`, and the `.` simply says that folder (ie snippy) is **invisible** and will only be seen if you ask the file browser `nautilus` to make it **visible**.

   - Now to create `~/.snippy` you can do it in two ways:

     1. From terminal:

        ```
        mkdir ~/.snippy OR mkdir /home/your_username/.snippy
        ```
     2. Form `nautilus` in your home directory `right click anywhere` and select command `new folder` from context menu and **most importantly** name it `.snippy`

[image]

2. Creating short cut for `snippy`:

   - go to `system settings > keyboard > shortcuts > custom shortcuts`

[image]

[image]

- click on the `+` sign then add a name say `snippy` then **enter the command to start snippy from terminal**. Which should be say `snippy`
- If not sure of the command check it with `which snippy` or `whereis snippy` it should return something like:

  ```
  /usr/bin/snippy 
  # this is the binary file that launches snippy.
  ```
- Then Click Disabled in the row that was just added. When it changes to New accelerator…, hold down the desired shortcut key combination.

**Note:**

When adding `snippy` to your path as demonstrated in the tutorial please do `$ sudo mv snippy.sh /usr/bin/snippy`. Not what is stated in the tutorial, so you can run just `snippy` from terminal..

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html